# Delete One To One relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have these classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="a")
class A{
  private Integer aId;
  private B b;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id_a")
  public Integer getAId() {
return aId;
  }

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table (name= "b")
class B{
    private A a;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_a")
    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

}
```

And tables look like:

> A) | id_A |....other fields...|
>
> B) | id_B | fk_id_A |..other fields..|

But, when I try to delete an instance of A, I get,

> org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException:
>   deleted object would be re-saved by
>   cascade :
>           (remove deleted object from associations)[B#130]

I've tried setting null on cross references:

```
b.setA(null) 
a.setB(null)
```

But exception still gets thrown.

All that I have accomplished is to delete a row in A, and leave B's foreign Key null, but when i re try to delete B, get the same error.

This is my delete code:

```
public static void delete(Object object) throws Exception {
        Transaction tx = getSession().beginTransaction();       
        try {
            getSession().delete(object);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            tx.rollback();
            getSession().close();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

`getSession` always returns a valid session.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from top and continue working down. You need to delete the reference to A in table B. So locate the reference in B of the record you're trying to delete in A and delete that record in B. Then go back to A and delete the record in A.

If you're using SQL Server, you can set cascading delete on table A and this will be done for you automatically. You have to be careful with this though. I wouldn't recommend this for complex structures.

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing the nulling of cross-references in a separate transaction? Those changes may need to be committed for the delete to work.